# Running artisan queue:work with additional arguments

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, supervisord, laravel-artisan

I am trying to run queued jobs, and pass additional parameters through the command line.  My use case is this:

I have 4 running `queue:work` processes through supervisor.  The jobs in my queue all require access to a proxy server, through which i can only have 4 processes running at any given time.  When I start up a queued job, I have to find a process number (1 through 4) that is not currently being used, then run my command through that process.

I have been using a database table to store the processes and it has a column for `in_use` which keeps track of whether its being used, but the problem I'm seeing is when two `queue:work` commands run simultaneously, the same proxy process can be picked from the database for both.

**What I want**

`php artisan queue:work --process=1`

Then to somehow retrieve that argument inside the job, so I can run my 4 processes each in supervisor separately.

As a workaround, I have created a custom artisan command which will take the argument, but I then lose the queue functionality.  I don't want to have to develop a custom queue process.

Is there a way to pass this argument?  Or, alternatively, is there a way that I could pop jobs off the queue from within my custom artisan command, and then run them manually rather than through `queue:work`?

Comment: Why not make dedicated queue's for those processes? You can then specify to which queue your task should be pushed and that way it is automatically using the connection you want for the proxy?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#pushing-jobs-onto-the-queue see the part Specifying The Queue For A Job

Comment: This may be what I end up doing.... How would you get the process ID from inside the job though?  I guess when I am trying to create a job, I could query the `jobs` table for how many jobs are queued on each process, and then push the job onto the smallest queue, and pass that same process ID into the job constructor?

Comment: It is hard for me to tell you how to do it cause I dont know the structure of your code. I hope that you figure out a way to make it work for you!

Comment: @ThomasSnijder I did end up doing things this way, you're welcome to post an answer I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be solved by using dedicated queue's. So each queue has a specific proxy process attached to it. The only thing left is to create a function/process to determine to which queue the process should go.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#pushing-jobs-onto-the-queue

Check out the part: Specifying The Queue For A Job