# Laravel 5.6. Attach state to a queue worker

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-queue

Is it possible somehow to attach state to a queue worker.

For example

`queue:work --on-account=some@mail.com`

and then use this `--on-account` variable in jobs.

The basic idea is that I can have only one worker per account due to some limitations. And it will never change. So the only way to scale is to add more accounts.

Each job can be processed with any account.

I will accept

> It's not possible because of XYZ. Use this technique to achieve the same result.

As an answer too.

P.S.

This is **not** a duplication of [Running artisan queue:work with additional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368641/running-artisan-queuework-with-additional-arguments) because his answer is not suitable in my case.

Comment: Are you workers working on multiple jobs or only on one specific job?

Comment: @milo526 on multiple jobs. Each job can be executed by ANY worker, but any worker SHOULD work (execute jobs) only with ONE specific account.

Answer (score 2):

How about using env vars?

you would run your queue as follows:

`export ACCOUNT="some@email";php artisan queue:work`

and then, in the worker you'd

`$account getenv('ACCOUNT');`

The other idea might be to use connections functionality:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#running-the-queue-worker

Quoting

> You may also specify which queue connection the worker should utilize. The connection name passed to the work command should correspond to one of the connections defined in your  config/queue.php configuration file:
>
> php artisan queue:work redis
>
> You may customize your queue worker even further by only processing particular queues for a given connection. For example, if all of your emails are processed in an emails queue on your  redis queue connection, you may issue the following command to start a worker that only processes only that queue:
>
> php artisan queue:work redis --queue=emails

That, probably will be the cleanest solution as far as laravel is concerned at least.
Unless I am missing what's exactly an issue.

Comment: I don't remember a solution back there, but your suggestion with .envs seems like the cleanest/best one. I can't accept, because I haven't tested it out, BUT I've upvoted. Thanks.